# Keep Existing Namespaces when overwriting XML file with ElementTree and Python

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have an XML file in the following format

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<foo>
   <bar>
      <bat>1</bat>
   </bar>
   <a>
      <b xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
         <c>1</c>
      </b>
   </a>
</foo>
```

I want to change the value of bat to '2' and change the file to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<foo>
   <bar>
      <bat>2</bat>
   </bar>
   <a>
      <b xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
         <c>1</c>
      </b>
   </a>
</foo>
```

I open this file by doing this

```
tree = ET.parse(filePath)
root = tree.getroot()
```

I then change the value of bat to '2' and save the file like this:

```
tree.write(filePath, "utf-8", True, None, "xml")
```

The value of bat successfully changes to 2, but the XML file now looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<foo xmlns:ns0="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
   <bar>
      <bat>2</bat>
   </bar>
   <a>
      <ns0:b>
         <ns0:c>1</ns0:c>
      </ns0:b>
   </a>
</foo>
```

In order to fix the issue of having a namespace named ns0, I do the following before parsing the document

```
ET.register_namespace('', "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1")
```

This gets rid of the ns0 namepace but the xml file now looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<foo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
   <bar>
      <bat>2</bat>
   </bar>
   <a>
      <b>
         <c>1</c>
      </b>
   </a>
</foo>
```

What do I do to get the output I need?

Comment: What version of Python and lxml are you using? I'm not able to reproduce that behavior. `tree.write(filePath, "utf-8", True, None, "xml")` throws an error on Python 3.5 -- Try doing your arguments explicitly: `tree.write("output.xml",xml_declaration=True,encoding="utf-8",pretty_print=True)`

Comment: I'm using Python version 3.5.1.  Not sure what lxml is - I started using Python yesterday.

Comment: I tried it and explicitly specifying arguments makes no difference.

Comment: Very similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/38438921/407651

Comment: @mzjn - yes, you are right.  Unfortunately there is no answer there either.

Comment: If you are OK with using a toolkit that is not in the standard library, then take a look at lxml. It is is similar to ElementTree (an extension of the same basic API) but more powerful. http://lxml.de/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know there isn't a way by the means of `xml.etree.ElementTree` methods to achieve your goal. By digging in the `xml.etree` source code and the `xml` specification I found that the library behaviour is not wrong, nor unreasonable. Anyway it does not allows the output you are looking for.

To achieve your goal using that library you have to customize rendering behaviour. To best suite your needs I have written the following `render` function.

```py
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
from re import findall, sub

def render(root, buffer='', namespaces=None, level=0, indent_size=2, encoding='utf-8'):
    buffer += f'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="{encoding}" ?>\n' if not level else ''
    root = root.getroot() if isinstance(root, ET.ElementTree) else root
    _, namespaces = ET._namespaces(root) if not level else (None, namespaces)
    for element in root.iter():
        indent = ' ' * indent_size * level
        tag = sub(r'({[^}]+}\s*)*', '', element.tag)
        buffer += f'{indent}<{tag}'
        for ns in findall(r'{[^}]+}', element.tag):
            ns_key = ns[1:-1]
            if ns_key not in namespaces: continue
            buffer += ' xmlns' + (f':{namespaces[ns_key]}' if namespaces[ns_key] != '' else '') + f'="{ns_key}"'
            del namespaces[ns_key]
        for k, v in element.attrib.items():
            buffer += f' {k}="{v}"'
        buffer += '>' + element.text.strip() if element.text else '>'
        children = list(element)
        for child in children:
            sep = '\n' if buffer[-1] != '\n' else ''
            buffer += sep + render(child, level=level+1, indent_size=indent_size, namespaces=namespaces)
        buffer += f'{indent}</{tag}>\n' if 0 != len(children) else f'</{tag}>\n'
    return buffer
```

By supplying to the above `render()` function your `xml` input data as follows:

```py
data =\ 
'''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<foo>
   <bar>
      <bat>1</bat>
   </bar>
   <a>
      <b xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
         <c>1</c>
      </b>
   </a>
</foo>'''

root = ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring(data))
ET.register_namespace('', "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1")
print(render(root))
```

It prints out the output your are looking for:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<foo>
  <bar>
    <bat>1</bat>
  </bar>
  <a>
    <b xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <c>1</c>
    </b>
  </a>
</foo>
```

Comment: The OP wants the value of the `<bat>` element to be 2 in the output.

Comment: @mzjn You're right. Anyway he is able to achieve that. The answer addresses what the OP ask help for.

Answer (score 1):

Using package `lxml` can helps solve your problem. An example with original/modified xml file and python code (using `lxml`) package, with the namespace/xml structure unchanged, has been provided here:
[example with namespace/xml structure unchanged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35574815/how-to-force-elementtree-to-keep-xmlns-attribute-within-its-original-element/66123074#66123074)