# xml to string and string to xml

Tags: xml, python-2.7, elementtree

I am trying to convert xml to string and string to xml.

Input xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<records>
        <record id="1">
                <url>https://www.google.com</url>
                <data>
                        <a xmlns="http://localhost:8080/">
                                <b>1</b>
                                <c>Mayur</c>
                        </a>
                </data>
        </record>
        <record id="2">
                <url>https://www.google.com</url>
                <data>
                        <a xmlns="http://localhost:8080/">
                                <b>2</b>
                                <c>chavda</c>
                        </a>
                </data>
        </record>
</records>
```

I can't get same xml file when i convert string to xml

```
tree = ET.parse(xmlfilepath)
root = tree.getroot()
print (tree.tostring(root))
```

xmlnx moved to records tag.

```
<records xmlns:ns0="http://localhost:8080/">
            <record id="1">
                    <url>https://www.google.com</url>
                    <data>
                            <ns0:a>
                                    <ns0:b>1</ns0:b>
                                    <ns0:c>Mayur</ns0:c>
                            </ns0:a>
                    </data>
            </record>
            <record id="2">
                    <url>https://www.google.com</url>
                    <data>
                            <ns0:a>
                                    <ns0:b>2</ns0:b>
                                    <ns0:c>chavda</ns0:c>
                            </ns0:a>
                    </data>
            </record>
    </records>
```

Can i get same xml as output which i have given as a input?
What is the reason for changing xml attribute and adding ns0:, ns1:  ?

Comment: `tree.tostring(root)` didn't work. Maybe you meant `ET.tostring(root)`? Anyway this seems to be a buggy behavior of `xml.etree.ElementTree`. The same didn't happen using `lxml.etree.ElementTree` ..

Comment: Let me try with lxml. Thanks

Comment: Two related, unanswered questions: http://stackoverflow.com/q/38663191/407651, http://stackoverflow.com/q/38438921/407651