# prevent ElementTree from adding namespaces to every element

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I'm using ElementTree in Python to parse an xml file and add or remove elements in it.

In my XML file the root and the elements just below the root have a namespace, but all the other elements do not.

I see that ElementTree, when printing the modified tree, adds namespaces to every element.

Is there a proper way of telling ElementTree to **just keep namespaces in the elements where they originally appeared**?

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15641319/4288043) what you're after? Looks like it's a hack where you modify the whole tree with a regular expression before running the parser on it.

Comment: Hmm... looks like a violent hack. I don't want to remove namespaces all together, I would like to keep them where they appear in the original file.

Comment: Does that also happen with _**unmodified**_ tree? "_I see that ElementTree, when printing the modified tree, adds namespaces to every element._"

Comment: Yes. I also noticed that some inner elements that were unaltered by my code had their original namespace removed and replaced by that of the parent subtree...

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/38438921/407651 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/38663191/407651

Comment: Yes, similar to questions that never received an answer. So I suppose there's no solution...

Comment: As I commented in https://stackoverflow.com/q/38663191/407651, if you can use lxml (http://lxml.de) instead of ElementTree, then that is a solution, I think.

Comment: @RickyRobinson, I post a solution,  with the namespace/xml structure unchanged, hope it helps. The link here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35574815/how-to-force-elementtree-to-keep-xmlns-attribute-within-its-original-element/66123074#66123074

Answer (score 3):

Try with this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
namespaces = {
    '':         'http://tempuri.org/',
    'soap':     'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/',
    'xsi':      'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance',
    'xsd':      'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema',
}
for prefix, uri in namespaces.items():
    ET.register_namespace(prefix, uri)
```